# Sed not matching a regex pattern it should match

Tags: json, regex, sed

I am using sed to replace the value of a key, but sed doesn't seem to be matching the regex properly. The JSON I have resembles this,

```
...
   "env": {
        "emailBxUrl": "placeholder"
    },
...
```

and the sed command I have is this,

```
sed -i "s/^(\ |\t)+\"emailBxUrl\"\:.*$/test/gm file1.json
```

After running the command, the file did not change. I checked the regex at [regexr](https://regexr.com/), and it found the "emailBxUrl ..." line just fine as shown below

[image]

So what am I missing for the sed command to not work as intended?

Comment: online sites won't work for sed because sed supports only BRE/ERE flavor of regex... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y  ... this might work for GNU sed `sed 's/^[ \t]\+"emailBxUrl":.*/test/'` but you really should avoid regex in first place for json.. use json parser like jq or python with json module, etc see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: You must add -E to sed command

Comment: post the extended json content

Comment: I agree with Sundeep that JSON data demands a JSON parser. However, try this to reduce your backslashitis: `sed -ri 's/^[[:blank:]]+"emailBxUrl":.*$/test/gm' file1.json` -- You are apparently already using GNU sed (due to the `m` modifier to s///), so the `-r` option enables extended regexes.

Comment: Expecting some regexp that worked in some online site to work in all command line tools is not useful given every command line tool supports specific regexp types (e.g. BREs, EREs, PCREs) given specific options and with specific caveats (e.g. delimiters in sed, whether it's dynamic or not in awk, etc.). Forget about those online regexp verification sites if you're actually planning to use a command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the comments, I decided to use jq, but to answer the question in case anyone really wants to use sed, glenn jackman's suggestion worked for me

```
sed -ri 's/^[[:blank:]]+"emailBxUrl":.*$/test/gm' file1.json
```